# i can't access my website in other computer using domain name but can access using IP address

Tags: iis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc3sh.png)I can access my website in my computer using my ip address 192.168.X.X.

I can access my website in my computer using domain name local.firstsite.com

=======================================================================

I can access my website in other computer using my ip address 192.168.X.X

i can't access my website in other computer using domain name

My question is how to access my website in other computer in the same network using  domain name.

i configure my web page using iis in windows server and the two machine in same domain

Comment: Are you running DNS on your domain?  Is that domain name registered in your DNS?

Comment: yes and  create A record in the domain

Comment: i have two servers the one hosting the web page in a different machine and my DNS configure in the other server but the machine hosting the web page under that domain

Comment: From both machines, try to ping local.firstsite.com to see if they both are getting the right IP address from DNS. If they are not then look at `ipconfig /all` to confirm that they are pointed at the right DNS, and not using the one from your router or gw.

Comment: On the other computer, open command prompt and run `nslookup local.firstsite.com`. Edit your question to include its output.

Comment: i have tried to ping the local.firstsite.com from both machines didn't receive any response  but if i ping both ip address get a reply .'

Comment: for nslookup the response to local.firstsite.com it multiple IP addresses not in mine

Answer (score 1):

The easist way to achieve this is register local.firstsite.com in other computer's hosts file.

If you have an active domain, then you need to create a DNS forward lookup zone for firstsite.com and create cname **local** for firstsite.com. As long as your internal network share the same DNS Server and create IIS binding for the domain. The website should be accessed from domain name.